# Setting elements with jQuery, what did I miss.

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");
let accountBalance = $("#accountBalance");
let stockPrice = $("#stockPrice");
accountBalance = parseInt(accountBalance);
stockPrice = parseFloat(stockPrice);


// const div = document.getElementById('div');

$("#display").hide();

let amountPerTrade = function amountPerTrade() {
    return accountBalance / 4;
}

// Returns shares that are allowed per trade
let sharesPerTrade = function sharesPerTrade() {
    const amountPerTrade = accountBalance / 4;
    return Math.floor(amountPerTrade / stockPrice);
}

// Returns amount that should be calculated for limit and stop amounts
function getExitAmount(percentage) {
    let amount = ((accountBalance * percentage) / sharesPerTrade()).toFixed(2);
    return amount;
}



let limitPrice = function limitPrice() {
    return getExitAmount(.03) + stockPrice;
}

let stopPrice = function stopPrice() {
    return stockPrice - getExitAmount(.01);
}

let possibleProfit = function possibleProfit() {
    return (getExitAmount(.03) * sharesPerTrade()).toFixed(2);
}

let possibleLoss = function possibleLoss() {
    return (getExitAmount(.01) * sharesPerTrade()).toFixed(2);
}



$("form").submit(function () {
    $("form").hide();

    $("#amountPerTrade").html(amountPerTrade);
    $("#sharesPerTrade").html(sharesPerTrade);
    $("#limitPrice").html(limitPrice);
    $("#stopPrice").html(stopPrice);
    $("#possibleProfit").html(possibleProfit);
    $("#possibleLoss").html(possibleLoss);


    $("#display").show();
    return false;
});

$("#reset").click(function (){
  $("form").show();

  $("#display").hide();
  return false;
});
```

So this is my js code, all my id's in the HTML correspond. I've checked rechecked and checked again. I know I'm missing something stupid here. But every time I run it either nothing is put into the HTML element or I NaN. 
The full code is at https://github.com/rustycomer/stock-strategy-calculator/tree/Update2.0

Comment: if it is NaN convert both values into numbr of use parseFloat

Comment: I did on line 4 and 5

Comment: i just checked your github code and cloned everything is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems in your code. 
I have made some changes on it so the result can be shown now. You can have a check first.

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");
let accountBalance = $("#accountBalance")[0].value;
let stockPrice = $("#stockPrice")[0].value;



// const div = document.getElementById('div');

$("#display").hide();

let amountPerTrade = function amountPerTrade() {
    return accountBalance / 4;
}

// Returns shares that are allowed per trade
let sharesPerTrade = function sharesPerTrade() {
    let amountPerTrade = accountBalance / 4;
    return Math.floor(amountPerTrade / stockPrice);
}

// Returns amount that should be calculated for limit and stop amounts
function getExitAmount(percentage) {
    let amount = (((accountBalance) * percentage) / sharesPerTrade()).toFixed(2);
    return amount;
}



let limitPrice = function() {
    return getExitAmount(.03) + stockPrice;
}

let stopPrice = function() {
    return stockPrice - getExitAmount(.01);
}

let possibleProfit = function() {
    return (getExitAmount(.03) * sharesPerTrade()).toFixed(2);
}

let possibleLoss = function() {
    return (getExitAmount(.01) * sharesPerTrade()).toFixed(2);
}



$("form").submit(function () {
    $("form").hide();
    accountBalance = parseInt(accountBalance[0].value);
    stockPrice = parseInt(stockPrice[0].value);
    $("#amountPerTrade").html(amountPerTrade());
    $("#sharesPerTrade").html(sharesPerTrade());
    $("#limitPrice").html(limitPrice());
    $("#stopPrice").html(stopPrice());
    $("#possibleProfit").html(possibleProfit());
    $("#possibleLoss").html(possibleLoss());

    $("#display").show();
    return false;
});

$("#reset").click(function (){
  $("form").show();

  $("#display").hide();
  return false;
});
```

The major problem of your code is that the variables or functions did not manipulate properly. 
In your `$("form").submit(function() { })`, `$(target).html()` can receive the html code you want to insert but not the function you have declared. You need to execute those function to get the returned value for insertion. 
Also, in line 2 to 3, you have to get the value from the input but not the `$(target)`. 
Finally, please be careful the differences between `var`, `let` and `const`. They can make you crazy if you use them incorrectly. 
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

not sure ,but it run and i hv chg u code to my code style

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");
$("#display").hide();

$("form").submit(function () 
{
    $("form").hide();

 var accountBalance = $("#accountBalance").val();
 var stockPrice = $("#stockPrice").val();

 function amountPerTrade() 
 {
  return accountBalance / 4;
 }
 
 // Returns shares that are allowed per trade
 function sharesPerTrade() 
 {
  //const amountPerTrade = accountBalance / 4;
  //return Math.floor(amountPerTrade() / stockPrice);
  return (amountPerTrade() / stockPrice);
 }
 
 // Returns amount that should be calculated for limit and stop amounts
 function getExitAmount(percentage) 
 {
  return ((accountBalance * percentage) / sharesPerTrade()).toFixed(2);
 }
 
 function limitPrice() 
 { 
  return getExitAmount(0.03) + stockPrice;
 }
 
 function stopPrice() 
 {    
  return stockPrice - getExitAmount(0.01);
 }
 
 function possibleProfit() 
 {
  return (getExitAmount(0.03) * sharesPerTrade()).toFixed(2);
 }
 
 function possibleLoss() 
 {
  return (getExitAmount(0.01) * sharesPerTrade()).toFixed(2);
 }

 accountBalance = parseInt(accountBalance);
 stockPrice = parseFloat(stockPrice);


// const div = document.getElementById('div');

    $("#amountPerTrade").html(amountPerTrade());
    $("#sharesPerTrade").html(sharesPerTrade());
    $("#limitPrice").html(limitPrice());
    $("#stopPrice").html(stopPrice());
    $("#possibleProfit").html(possibleProfit());
    $("#possibleLoss").html(possibleLoss());


    $("#display").show();
    return false;
});

$("#reset").click(function (){
  $("form").show();

  $("#display").hide();
  return false;
});
```

[image]